# Code indentation not working after a list

Tags: support, markdown

Indented code does not display properly after a list item (bulleted or numbered). Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
(*some good code here*)
f[x]=1
```

A list:

- one
- two
- three

  (*some good code here*)
  f[x]=1

After a normal paragraph, everything is OK.

```
(*some good code here*)
f[x]=1
```

(I'm using win7 and Chrome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works, but you need to add some extra spaces.  It needs to be indented twice, to distinguish between a new paragraph within a single list item and actual code.

#### Example MarkDown

```
 * one

 * two

   two continued

        code
```

#### The above, formatted

> - one
> - two
>
>   two continued
>
>   ```
>   code
>   ```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! Do I just delete the question?

Comment: @Ajasja Don't delete it, I'm sure there are other people who are confused.  I was confused about this as well, and you got 2 upvotes in less than an hour.  We can retag it from 'bug' to 'markdown' and 'support' (I'll do that, adjust if necessary)

Comment: I would have never guessed such a solution, thanks Szabolcs!

Answer (score 3):

Szabolcs' answer works if you want to make the code part of the indented list. If you don't want to make it part of the indented list, a simple comment can be used to stop it. Example Markdown:

```
* point 1
* point 2

  point 2 continued

        (*this code is part of point 2.*)

  point 2 continued

<!-- this comment serves only to stop point 2 -->

    (*This code no longer belongs to point 2.*)
```

This gives:

> - point 1
> - point 2
>
>   point 2 continued
>
>   ```
>   (*this code is part of point 2.*)
>   ```
>
>   point 2 continued
>
> ```
> (*This code no longer belongs to point 2.*)
> ```

As you can see, the comment, while not being rendered itself, takes the function of stopping point 2.

Comment: How come that in the first example, the <!-- ... --> comment is visible? They are hidden only when quoted?

Comment: @IstvánZachar: Because in the first example, it is part of the code block, and thus not interpreted but displayed literally.

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense. Of course. Silly me. Thanks!